# assumed decimal as input - tab and enter add trailing zeros

Tags: cobol

Good evening,

I just started learning Cobol, and to practice, I wanted to program a simple multiplication program, working with two decimal numbers given by the user.

So I wrote the following

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. exo.

   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77 a PIC 9(2)V9.
   77 b PIC 9(2)V9.
   77 result PIC 9(4)V99.
   screen section.
   1 pla-title.
          2 blank screen.
          2 line 1 col 1 value 'Multiplication'.
   1 pls-numbers.
          2 line 4 col 2 value 'Number 1 : '.
          2 PIC 9(2)V9 to a required.
          2 line 5 col 2 value 'Number 2 : '.
          2 PIC 9(2)V9 to b required.
   1 pla-result.
          2 line 7 col 2 PIC 9(2)V9 from a.
          2 col 7 value 'x'.
          2 col 9 PIC 9(2)V9 from b.
          2 col 13 value '='.
          2 col 15 PIC 9(4)V99 from result.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   display pla-title.
   accept pls-numbers.
   compute result = a * b.
   display pla-result.

   END PROGRAM exo.
```

The issue here is not the multiplication part, which works perfectly. The problem is the input. Every time I press tab or enter, there is a 0 added at the end. For instance, typing 9,9,9,tab,9,9,9,enter multiplies 900 with 990, since the format only takes the last three digits of 99900 (tab+enter) and 9990 (enter).

I tried the same program with integers, it works perfectly. I tried the same with real decimals too (9(2).9), and the input works, but I have a problem with the multiplication (not a numeric value), that I will try to understand later, one problem at the time.

So in short, the question is to know why the input is modified by typing tab and enter, that in my understanding is used to navigate the accept fields.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Just wanted to add: this is a good question according to the tour which you should still follow to get your first badge ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have now done it. It is true that I learned some things in this tour :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How the input is automatically adjusted on field change/finish of the accept depends on the compiler/runtime actually in use (it is good in most times to add this information in the question), but most COBOL variants want a "." (or in the case of `DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA` a ",") entered to get the decimal part correct.

Actually the results with an implied decimal-point and `ACCEPT` may not be what you want it to do. I suggest to try using a numeric-edited field like `ZZ9.99` (which is auto-de-edited on `MOVE` to a field you do the calculation with [if the stored data matches the editing symbols] after the `ACCEPT`) or a plain `PIC X` and a `MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (input-field) TO a` afterwards (this should work on any compiler including this function).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. I had tried something similar to avoid the `not a numeric value` error, but I had not done it correctly.


The compiler is GnuCOBOL 2.2.0, sorry for forgetting this information. I had tried adding myself a "." or a "," in the input field, but it did not seem to work. I must confess that even though the problem is fixed, I still don't understand what was the issue with `ACCEPT` and implied decimal numbers.